# retrieve action window from a button openerp

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

In my module I want to view form from a button click.

this is my button "Postponed" with other workflow buttons

```
<header>
    <button string="Planned" type="workflow" name="action_planned" class="" icon="gtk-undo" states="postponed"/>
    <button string="Complete" type="workflow" name="action_complete" class="" icon="gtk-apply" states="planned, postponed"/>
    <button string="Postponed" type="action" name="%(timetable_postponed)d" class="" icon="gtk-jump-to"/>
    <button string="Cancel" type="workflow" name="action_cancel" class="" icon="gtk-cancel" states="planned, postponed"/>
    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" readonly="True" statusbar_visible="planned, completed, postponed, cancelled"/>
</header>
```

and this is my form view and action

```
    <record id="timetable_postponed_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">op.timetable.postponed</field>
        <field name="model">op.timetable</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Time Table Postponed" version="7.0">
                <field name="classroom_id" />
                <field name="period_id" />
                <field name="date" />
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <act_window id="timetable_postponed"
            name="Postponed Timetable"
            res_model="op.timetable"
            view_mode="form"
            view_id="timetable_postponed_view"
            target="new"
            />
```

and while updating I got this error

```
       raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
   ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: myschool.timetable_postponed" while parsing file:///E:/Development/MySchool-Src/OSBT_0374/myschool/op_timetable/op_timetable_view.xml:111, near
   <record id="view_op_timetable_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">op.timetable.form</field>
        <field name="model">op.timetable</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8"/>
        <field name="sequence" eval="4"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Time Table" version="7.0">
                <header>
                    <button string="Planned" type="workflow" name="action_planned" class="" icon="gtk-undo" states="postponed"/>
                    <button string="Complete" type="workflow" name="action_complete" class="" icon="gtk-apply" states="planned, postponed"/>
                    <button string="Postponed" type="action" name="%(timetable_postponed)d" class="" icon="gtk-jump-to"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" type="workflow" name="action_cancel" class="" icon="gtk-cancel" states="planned, postponed"/>
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" readonly="True" statusbar_visible="planned, completed, postponed, cancelled"/>
                </header>
                <sheet>
                    <separator colspan="4" string="Time Table"/>
                    <group colspan="4" col="4">
                        <field name="lecturer_id"/>
                        <field name="standard_id"/>
                        <field name="period_id"/>
                        <field name="subject_id"/>
                        <field name="classroom_id"/>
                        <field name="start_datetime"/>
                        <field name="end_datetime"/>
                        <field name="type"/>
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

what should I do to retrieve this new window on my button click event...?

Comment: below answer is helpful to you than please give feedback of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with calling action through button.

Whenever we try to call action in Button than we need to specified module name before action name, where actual action id is defind.

If you don't specified module name than it will take current module as a name and try to find that id in it.

Here is you code:

```
<button string="Postponed" type="action" name="%(timetable_postponed)d" class="" icon="gtk-jump-to"/>
```

neeed to change with this

```
name="%(module_name.timetable_postponed)d"
```